# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests_html'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm trying to use the module requests-html in Mac OS 10.14, it presents this error both when trying to install with the pip and with easy_install it presents the error saying that there is already this module. I did a test on windows and the commands worked correctly, and installed it via direct pip in CMD, could someone help me?

Pip installation
[image: instalacao com pip]
Easy_install installation
[image: instalacao com easy_install]
Windows 10 installation
[image: instalacao no Windows 10]

Comment: Do you want to import module in Python 3.X interpreter?

Comment: i saw [here](https://pypi.org/project/requests-html) that `request-html` requires `Python >=3.6.0` but in your `macOS X` image I am seeing that it is going under `.../Python/2.7`.

Comment: Yeap, i did install the last version of python 3.7.1, and also didnt worked, and the pip version is 18.0.

Comment: Try using pip3 instead of pip. This will install using the python 3 version of pip.

Comment: Could you tell me how???

Comment: Just execute `pip3 install requests-html`. Note that `pip` will install library for Python 2.X, `pip3` - for Python 3.X. Libraries installed for specific interpreter version are not accessible for another version

Comment: Where is the error in your code?

Comment: The answer that the Andersson  give me, work like a charm

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. make sure you have Python 3.6 or higher.
2. Execute `pip3 install requests-html`.

Thanx **Andersson** for the answer. I can not leave comments (yet), so I wrote the reply here.

Answer (score 0):

trying requests html on windows, but no success, posting pics of the situation:
[image: requests html deps satisfied installed via pip3]

[image: trying to run requests according to the manual pages]